# Poor performance when running Unity as embedded window in application

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-game-engine, windows-10

I am trying to run a Unity application via the following code:

```
IntPtr parentHandle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(_pathToUnityExe);
Logging.Log_Critical.Send("Starting process at " + _pathToUnityExe);

if (_useEmbeddedWindow)
{
    procInfo.Arguments = "-parentHWND " + parentHandle + " " + Environment.CommandLine;
    procInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    procInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
}

_externalAppProcess = Process.Start(procInfo);
```

I've been noticing somewhat poor performance on the parent WPF app side, namely sluggish responsiveness and hitching with animations and media. This seems to occur whether the Unity app is loading a complex scene or a completely blank one.

Since the Unity app is being started through a process, I don't imagine there is threading/blocking problem, but I'm not sure what else it could be unless this is an issue in Unity.

**Does anyone have thoughts or experience with this?**

I'm open to other approaches as well if needed, I mainly just need to be able to control the Unity window's size and position. I'm mostly suspicious of the `-parentHWND` argument causing weird behavior on Unity's side.

However, this code doesn't seem to remove the window title bar on its own, is there a way to do that without using the `-parentHWND` argument?

```
procInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

Comment: Have you tried opening up the profiler and seeing what is eating up your precious frames?

Comment: @Vakore That was one of the first things I tried, unfortunately VS was giving me a failed to start profiler error. I'll have to try one of the Windows performance tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution ended up being to simply not use the embedded window flag when starting the Unity executable as a process. I then didn't need any arguments to be set in the `StartProcessInfo` object.

On the Unity side of things, I have a script that is in the initial scene which ensures the Unity application doesn't have the Windows title bar decorations. In that script's `start` override method I have:

```
Screen.fullScreen = true;
```